# Insert new Div below the div clicked

Tags: javascript

How to insert a new node(create with javascript) under the clicked node?.

At the moment it crosses the original div, I do not want that it crosses, it should remain in its origin

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");

parent.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var currentSelection, currentRange, currentNode, newDiv, newContent;

  currentSelection = window.getSelection();
  currentRange = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0);
  currentNode = currentRange.startContainer;
  console.log(currentNode.nodeValue);

  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = 'nuevo';
  newContent = document.createTextNode("holanda");
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
  this.appendChild(newDiv)

});
```

```css
.nuevo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  z-index: 3;
}

#parent>div {
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">

  <div>hello</div>
  <div> *** </div>
  <div>world</div>

</div>
```

result:

when clicked the word `world`
[image]

when clicked the word `***`
[image]

Comment: Not the answer to your latest question, but if you look at the last question, I edited it to remove the `if` statement, which is no longer necessary.

Comment: If you are looking to simply have it rendered below the clicked element, I don't think you want or need `insertBefore` at all. Just use `this.appendChild(newDiv)` and adjust its position to be the same as `event.target`, but with `margin-top:1em;`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i edited my question, but not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing the `offsetLeft` property to locate new append elements:

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let rootElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.root");
for (let i = 0; i < rootElements.length; i++ ) {
    rootElements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var currentSelection, currentRange, currentNode, newDiv, newContent;
        currentSelection = window.getSelection();
        currentRange = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0);
        currentNode = currentRange.startContainer;
        // console.log(currentNode.nodeValue);
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.className = 'nuevo';
        newContent = document.createTextNode("holanda");
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
        let xPos = event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
        let newEle = parent.appendChild(newDiv);
        newEle.style.left = xPos + "px";
   });
}
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}

.nuevo {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.root {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class = "root">hello</div>
  <div class = "root">***</div>
  <div class = "root">world</div>
</div>
```

**Update: one more way to achieve the goal**

Append every new stack which actually has the same number of elements as first line. Utilize `display: flex` property on every new stack, and then give the inner elements corresponding width as same as their ancestor by `flex-basis` (why not width? this is another problem because of characteristic of `flex` property).

And let content of that only element which we want for visibly appending to extend the space for itself.

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let rootElements = document.querySelectorAll("div.root");
for (let i = 0; i < rootElements.length; i++ ) {
    rootElements[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        newStack = document.createElement("div");
        newStack.className = 'stack';
        
        for (let j = 0; j < rootElements.length; j++) {
            let grid = document.createElement("div");
            grid.className = 'flexItem';
            grid.setAttribute("style", "flex-basis:" + rootElements[j].getBoundingClientRect().width + "px");

            if (i===j) {
                grid.className += ' nuevo';
                grid.textContent = 'holanda';
            }
            newStack.appendChild(grid)
        }
        parent.appendChild(newStack);
   });
}
```

```css
#parent {
  font-size: 0px; // For eliminating gap between inline-blocks
}

.stack {
  display: flex;
}

.flexItem {
  flex: 0 1;
}

.nuevo {
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.root {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class = "root">hello</div>
  <div class = "root">*******</div>
  <div class = "root">world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the width of the new div must not be 100%

Comment: @x-rw, so you just need one click?

Comment: I need the new div to appear just below the word that is clicked

Comment: @x-rw, I mean if you have more than one click, the new div would squeeze each other, should this situation need to be concerned?

Comment: all should be stacked under

Comment: @x-rw, I've updated the answer, is this what you want?

Comment: @x-rw, one more choice appended.

Comment: waooo beautiful answer

Answer (score -1):

Attach the event listener to each one of the divs inside `parent` so that you can use them to append your elements, also, change the display property of `nuevo` to `block`

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll("#parent > div");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = 'nuevo';
    newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("holanda"));
    newDiv.style.left = this.offsetLeft + 'px';
    this.parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
  });
}
```

```css
.nuevo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

#parent>div {
  float: left;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div> *** </div>
  <div>world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer not should create a space when click in ***

Comment: @x-rw, I edited the answer to use the `offsetLeft` of the cliked element as the left margin of the inserted element